# Como rodar arquivo .vbs ao iniciar o Windows

Tags: vbs, inicialização

Como eu poderia rodar um arquivo .vbs quando  windows iniciar, consigo fazer um arquivo .bat rodar pelo regedit.

Já coloquei um .bat para abrir o .vbs, fiz dessa forma

```
cscript "C:\teste.vbs"
exit
```

Comment: @Henrique até chamei o vbs pelo bat, mas ele ficou com o cmd aberto(mesmo eu colocando exit no final)

Comment: @Henrique Pronto, atualizei

Comment: Tente alterar o `cscript`por `start`.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Update** ***Respondendo:***

O comando que **adiciona** uma entrada no registro, instruindo a execução de um **comando** / **arquivo** em cada inicialização do sistema via linha de **comando** / **bat:**

```bat
rem :: Obs.: O \" é para "escapar" as aspas no comando Reg Add adicionando no registro::
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v Run_VBS /t reg_sz /d "\"C:\teste.vbs\""
```

---

Para **excluir** / **desfazer** a entrada pela linha de **comando** /**bat**:

```bat
delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v Run_VBS /f
```

---

---

**Update** ***Informações adicionais pertinentes & exemplo de uso/aplicação:***

Adicionar instruções para execução de um **script VBS** na **inicialização do Windows**, vai implicar em escolher duas coisas:

1) **Onde adicionar** ?

2) Como **remover** depois que **não são mais necessárias**?

---

Sobre o **Onde**:

Como uma **sugestão**, o código abaixo foi escrito para usar a **Chave:**
**<kbd>`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`</kbd>**

Você pode **editar** para atender vossas necessidades observando as explicações mais abaixo...

---

Sobre a **Remoção**:

O próprio **bat** remove as **entradas**/**valores** adicionados por ele na **chave**, ele identifica se os **valores** no **registro** para fazer a **remoção**.

Executando **uma vez**, ele vai criar as **entradas/valores** necessários no **registro**, porém, para quando **executado novamente**, e ele se encarrega de remover as **chaves**/**valores** das entradas por **ele** adicionados na **primeira execução**... 
O próprio **bat** vai criar um **VBS** para servir de teste...

**<kbd>[`StartUP_VBS.cmd`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210375/como-rodar-arquivo-vbs-ao-iniciar-o-windows)</kbd>**

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

rem :: aqui vc pode editar a variável "_hkl_run" conforme lhe atende considerando o comanentário abaixo ::
set _hkl_run_=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

( 
>"%temp%\_vbs_exemplo_teste.vbs" echo/ msgbox "VBS Boot Teste" ,4, "O que me diz, funciona?" 
) && ( set "_vbs_=%temp%\_vbs_exemplo_teste.vbs"
) || ( echo/ Erro criando vbs^!!
) 
timeout /t -1
>nul ((
reg query "!_hkl_run_!" | findstr /l /c:"Run_VBS" 2>nul >nul
) && (
reg delete "!_hkl_run_!" /v Run_VBS /f 
) || (
reg add "!_hkl_run_!" /v Run_VBS /t reg_sz /d "\"!_vbs_!\"" 
)) 2>nul 

rundll32.exe USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True
```

<kbd>**`Qual chave devo fazer uso e quando usar?`**</kbd>

**HKCU** ou **HKLM** e ainda, **RunOnce** ou **Run**

Opera para o **Usuário atual** ==> **HKCU**

Opera para **todos Usuários** ==> **HKLM**

Opera **uma vez** e **se exclui do Registro** ==> **RunOnce**

Opera **permanentemente** e **fica no Registro** ==> **Run**

---

**Obs.:#1** A chave **Run** mantem-se no **Registro** para **permanente execução** durante o **boot!**

**Obs.:#2** A chave **RunOnce** se apaga do **Registro** antes de ser **executada**, só **executa uma vez!**

---

Para execução **única** no próximo boot e para **qualquer usuário**, use essa chave:
**HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce**

---

Para execução **única** no próximo boot e apenas para o **usuário atual**, use:
**HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce**

---

Para a execução **continua/permanente**, apenas **usuário atual**, use:
**HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**

---

Para a execução **continua/permanente**, e para **qualquer usuário**, use:
**HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**

---

**Obs.:** Para usar um **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** que cria um **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)**, é necessário usar **[escape](/questions/tagged/escape)** **[quando os caracteres](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)** **[especiais](/questions/tagged/especiais)** não estiverem entre aspas: Exemplo:
  **<kbd>`^(, ^), ^{, ^}, ^&, ^>, ^<, etc...`</kbd>**

Esse **bat** vai gerar um **VBS** e adicionar uma entrada no registro necessária para após reiniciar o computador, ele rodar o **VBS**.
***Rodando abre essa janela abaixo:***
[image: tela após reiniciar]

---

Para **desfazer/remover/reverter** sem rodar o **bat** novamente, apenas use use/execute o **comando** abaixo:

**<kbd>`reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v Run_VBS /f`</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Se o arquivo roda normalmente após executar o bat basta copiá-lo para

> C:\Users\Your User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup\

Não esqueça de editar o *path* para o script no bat